# What do MongoDB oplog operations letters mean?

Tags: mongodb

What are different letters in MongoDB oplog "op" field means ? I can guess some of the letters meaning but I am not sure.

"n" = ?

"i" = insert , is this correct ?

"u" = update, is this correct ?

"c" = count, is this correct ?

I guess "d"= delete ?

what are other letters are there and what are their meanings ?

Answer (score 16):

From mongohq, these are the values that the op field can contain and their meanings. "i", "u", "d", "c", "db", "n":

> This is the “op” field
>   which indicates what operation took place. Its values can be “i” for
>   “insert”, “u” for “update”, and “d” for “delete”. For most oplog
>   tailing applications, you will only be interested in these three
>   values, but there is also a “c” for commands that affect databases at
>   a high level, “db” which apparently announces the presence of a
>   “database”, and “n” for “no-ops”, used for changes in the database or
>   collections which don’t result in a change in the stored data.
>
> Any of these operations will have been applied to a database or a
>   collection so the next field, “ns” tells us the “namespace” for this
>   operation.

http://blog.mongohq.com/the-mongodb-oplog-and-node-js/

Answer (score 3):

```
> use test
 switched to db test
> db.foo.insert({x:1})
> db.foo.update({x:1}, {$set : {y:1}})
> db.foo.update({x:2}, {$set : {y:1}}, true)
> db.foo.remove({x:1})
```

Now in oplog

```
> use local
switched to db local
> db.oplog.rs.find()
{ "ts" : { "t" : 1286821527000, "i" : 1 }, "h" : NumberLong(0), "op" : "n", "ns" : "", "o" : { "msg" : "initiating set" } }
{ "ts" : { "t" : 1286821977000, "i" : 1 }, "h" : NumberLong("1722870850266333201"), "op" : "i", "ns" : "test.foo", "o" : { "_id" : ObjectId("4cb35859007cc1f4f9f7f85d"), "x" : 1 } }
{ "ts" : { "t" : 1286821984000, "i" : 1 }, "h" : NumberLong("1633487572904743924"), "op" : "u", "ns" : "test.foo", "o2" : { "_id" : ObjectId("4cb35859007cc1f4f9f7f85d") }, "o" : { "$set" : { "y" : 1 } } }
{ "ts" : { "t" : 1286821993000, "i" : 1 }, "h" : NumberLong("5491114356580488109"), "op" : "i", "ns" : "test.foo", "o" : { "_id" : ObjectId("4cb3586928ce78a2245fbd57"), "x" : 2, "y" : 1 } }
{ "ts" : { "t" : 1286821996000, "i" : 1 }, "h" : NumberLong("243223472855067144"), "op" : "d", "ns" : "test.foo", "b" : true, "o" : { "_id" : ObjectId("4cb35859007cc1f4f9f7f85d") } }
```

> op: the write operation that should be applied to the slave. n
>   indicates a no-op, this is just an informational message.

```
>  i for inserts 
>  u for updates   
> and d for deletes
```

The o field now contains the document to insert or the criteria to update and remove. Notice that, for the update, there are two o fields (o and o2). o2 give the update criteria and o gives the modifications (equivalent to update()‘s second argument).